# Why Won't this Object UV Unwrap?

Tags: modeling

[image]I'm using Blender 2.83.1, and one of the objects in my scene won't UV unwrap. Every other object in the scene is ok, except the one. I've:

- Applied Rotation, Scale, Position
- Cleaned up the mesh
- Removed Doubles (merge by distance)
- Set the Origin to Geometry

Every other object in the scene and new objects all unwrap with no issues, so I don't think it's my UV settings. I've removed all modifiers and textures and shaders, but I still can't unwrap it. I know the object in question is one that I could easily recreate, but I'd like to know what happened before it happens to a much more complex object not so easily remade. I'd be grateful for any advice on this!

Here's a link to the file (thanks Batfinger, for telling me about this!):
[image]

UPDATE:
Thanks for testing the file, everyone! It helped me narrow down the problem (my nooooobishness) once I knew the file or Blender wasn't corrupt. For all of the other objects in my file, I could mark a seam in edit mode, click "A" to select all, and click "U" to unwrap the object in the UV editor. For this object, I had to click "UV">Unwrap to unwrap this object. I'm not sure why this object was different than the rest, but that's 'cause I a noob. I'm sure I'll learn what I did in time! Anyway, thanks again, everyone! –

Comment: It's possible an old UV map is getting in the way. Go to the Object Properties tab (green "triangle" above material properties tab), and under UV maps, click the minus button next to the UV map that is there. Then enter edit mode, select all, and unwrap again.

Comment: Recommend making a blend file with the headlight object appended and add link to question https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, there seems to be no other UV map attached.

Comment: Strange. No issue for me using test file. I am using 2.9 tho. Hopefully others will have a look.

Comment: Works for me as well (U - Unwrap) in 2.81

Comment: Thanks for testing the file, everyone! It helped me narrow down the problem (my nooooobishness) once I knew the file or Blender wasn't corrupt. For all of the other objects in my file, I could mark a seam in edit mode, click "A" to select all,  and click "U" to unwrap the object in the UV editor. For this object, I had to click "UV">Unwrap to unwrap this object. I'm not sure why this object was different than the rest, but that's 'cause I a noob. I'm sure I'll learn what I did in time!  Anyway, thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

**Unwrap shortcut <kbd>U</kbd> in *UV Editor* works only if any *UV Map* already exists.**
If in *Properties Editor > Data > UV Maps* is not listed any, it does nothing.

[image]

By default new objects are unwrapped, so if you modeled them and then just updated *UV Map* it works from *UV Editor* as well.